# Using temporal range in Atlas

Tags: qgis-3, atlas

In the [tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html) for Atlas it states

> The associated data-defined widgets help make the time range dynamic, and allow outputting temporal atlases, i.e. automated maps with fixed spatial extent and whose contents vary based on time. **For example, using as coverage layer a csv file with a start and end pair of fields and a number of rows representing date ranges**, enable both the temporal range and control by atlas in the map item properties and hit atlas export.

I can't get this to work, on the map item the control by atlas feature is not selectable as image. I wish to use the Atlas over the export from temporal control to allow additional control of the image and two parts of the map to animate on same frame

[image]

What I've tried:

0. Test map animates as designed using temporal controller in main map view outside print layout
1. Create a csv with columns row_id, start_date, stop_date. One row for each date range (for example row 1 start year 2020 stop 2021
2. Check the table date columns are date time and adjust if required
3. Create an atlas, use table (which has no geom) as coverage layer
4. Go to map item and pick temporal range

Atlas settings used:

[image]

Comment: What does not work in what you tried ?

Comment: the editor option for controlled by atlas is not available, there's no geom on my table with the date range

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is:

- set the Atlas coverage based on the table that you created, set the atlas pagename to the date field of that table (what you did as far as I understand)

[image]

- set the layer symbology to make its opacity to be 100 if "date"=@atlas_pagename, 0 otherwise: `case when "date"=@atlas_pagename then 100 else 0 end`

[image]

Export Atlas:
[image]

Note: One option to easily automate the creation of the table, is to create a `virtual layer` which takes your main data layer and is defined as:
`select * from your_temporal_layer_name group by the_date_field_name`

Comment: i thought i'd figures this out by making my symbology expression drive using your tip. currently symbology use `case when @map_start_time = year then yr_data` so i tried making the page name the year but this didn't work, i test with and without temporal range and making layers non temporal

Comment: I am not sure temporal mode & atlas are compatible (my understanding is that they are separate ways of segmenting/representing the related data). That's why the temporal filtering of the layer is disabled when Atlas is selected

Comment: maybe that is correct but the tutorial on the docs explicity states they are, thank you for your help i can see a way to use the page_number for now it's not working for me